# Import error for react-icons. Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io' in '/usr/src/app/src/...'

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

In my React app, which was built using create-react-app, I'm getting the error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io' in '/usr/src/app/src/components/analytics_components'.

The app has been working fine for a while but I just rebuilt it using Docker Compose and now it's not.

It seems like it's looking in the wrong directory, `src` instead of `node_modules`.

react-icons is definitely installed, *npm list react-icons* returns its version number.

I can see the *io* folder in *node_modules/react-icons*

The import statement:

```
import { IoMdList } from "react-icons/io";
```

When I change the import to explicitly point to the node_modules directory, it works, but I didn't need to do this before nor do I need to for any other packages, which are still all working correctly:

```
import { IoMdList } from "../../../node_modules/react-icons/io";
```

Comment: Did you (or does Docker Compose) eject Webpack?

Comment: @Atav32, no, Webpack's not ejected.

Answer (score 2):

I just reinstall the command  `npm install react-icons` and then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Again you can install npm if you already installed that doesn't matter you can re-install your npm again without deleting current node module. it works for me. command: npm install

Answer (score 0):

you can try delete your node module folder and run cmd:npm install or yarn install it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to import single icon like following:

```
import { GrLogout } from "react-icons/gr/GrLogout";
```

it couldn't find the icon the true way is

```
import { GrLogout } from "react-icons/gr";
```

importing all lib and then getting single icon.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been here for a while, I'll just share my solution in case someone still needs it.

Create a file called "all.js" with the following content, save the file to "node_modules\react-icons".

By right, the file should be created by "npm install" or "yarn install", but if it was not created correctly, just create it manually.

```
export * from './fa';
export * from './io';
export * from './io5';
export * from './md';
export * from './ti';
export * from './go';
export * from './fi';
export * from './gi';
export * from './wi';
export * from './di';
export * from './ai';
export * from './bs';
export * from './ri';
export * from './fc';
export * from './gr';
export * from './hi';
export * from './si';
export * from './im';
export * from './bi';
export * from './cg';
export * from './vsc';
```